# Differentiating this integral,

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, harmonic-functions

I want to show that $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ for the integral given below, so I think I want to differentiate under the integral with respect to both $x$ and $y$.  The goal is to show that $u$ is harmonic.  This is one part of an old complex analysis exam question, but I think this part of the problem is really an advanced calculus problem, dealing with the interchange of derivatives and integral, so I have added both the real analysis tag and complex analysis tag for anyone who's interested in answering.

So I've reviewed several versions of the Leibniz integral rule for differentiating under the integral sign, however, all of the versions have *variable limits*, whereas the integral below has constants in the lower and upper limits of integration, say, the constant limit $-R$ and $+R$, and letting $R \to \infty$ to turn it into an integral over the extended real line.

So, since there are no variable limits, is $u_x$ and $u_y$  just...immediately equal to $0$?  And so there's not even a need to check the second derivatives of $u$, and we can conclude that $u$ is harmonic in the upper half plane.  Of course, I am almost certain that this is not correct, but if I just follow what I reviewed regarding Leibniz's rule, this would seem to be the case.

What do you think?  Thanks,

The problem statement is:

If $f(x) = \sum_j c_j \sin(a_jx)$ is a finite trigonometric sum given on the real axis $y=0$, show that:

$$u(x,y) = \frac{|y|}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x+t)}{t^2+y^2}dt$$

is harmonic both on the upper half plane as well as the lower half plane, and that

$$\lim_{y \to 0} u(x,y) = f(x) $$

from either side.

Any hints or suggestions on how to get started on this problem are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: There are two parts to that Leibniz formula: one deals with the limits as functions, the other deals with the function you're integrating. Without worrying about hypotheses, you want to differentiate under the integral sign: If $u(x,y) = \int_a^b g(x,y,t)\,dt$, then $u_x = \int_a^b g_x(x,y,t)\,dt$ and $u_{xx} = \int_a^b g_{xx}(x,y,t)\,dt$, etc.

Comment: "I want to show that uxx+uyy=0" On what domain?

Comment: Thanks so much Professor Shifrin; I will try now and see what I come up with ... @TedShifrin,

Comment: Hi @zhw., I want to show that $u$ is harmonic in both the upper half plane as well as the lower half plane.  I am guessing that I would show it first for the UHP?  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: There is another part to this question @zhw., if you are interested:  it then asks whether another function exists that is harmonic in the entire plane but coincides with $f(x)$ on the real axis ... but I am not ready to think about that question just yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to differentiate under the integral sign. The given $f$ is a finite linear combination of functions of the form $t\mapsto e^{i\omega t}$.  Use residue calculus to compute once and for all
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{e^{i\omega t}\over t^2+y^2}\>dt={\pi\over y}\>e^{-y|\omega|}\qquad(y>0)\ .$$

Comment: Hi Professor Blatter, how does integrating $u$ explicitly establish that it is harmonic?  Shouldn't we be differentiating to show that $\nabla^2 u = 0$?  Thanks @ChristianBlatter,

Comment: Oo, sorry, $u$ is given as an integral.  I am guessing from here, using the result derived from residue calculus, I can show that $\nabla^2 u = 0$, i.e., differentiating twice in $x$ and in $y$, to conclude that it is harmonic @ChristianBlatter,

Comment: (I may not be clever enough to recognize the result as the real or imaginary part of some holomorphic function in the UHP, as zhw. does very easily.) @Christian Blatter.  I will try differentiating now, thanks, professor...

Comment: Hi Professor Blatter, I have finished my work here, I think.  The residue computations were simple, and it looks like I am just taking the imaginary part of a finite scalar (not linear anymore) combination of holomorphic functions.  And so the imaginary part must be harmonic, and I also immediately see that $lim_{y \to 0} u(x,y) = f(x)$, too.  In fact we have scalar combinations of *entire* functions, in the form of $\large c_j e^{-a_jy}e^{i a_j x}$.

Comment: And from inspection we see that $u(x,y) = u(x,-y)$, which forces $u$ to be harmonic in the lower half plane, too.  Thanks so much for your time, Professor Blatter.  @ChristianBlatter,

Comment: Hi Professor Blatter, can I squeeze in a last question regarding this problem statement, if you don't mind?  Even though we've shown that $u$ is harmonic in both the UHP and LHP, and it equals to the finite trigonometric sum $f(x)$ at $y=0$, apparently such a function $u$ cannot be harmonic on the *entire* plane.  How can we justify this claim?  I know that it is likely a boundedness argument and an application of Liouville's Theorem, but right now I am not able to say it explicitly.  What do you think?  Thanks, @ChristianBlatter,

Answer (score 3):

For the upper half plane, rewrite as

$$u(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y}{(t-x)^2+y^2}\,f(t)\,dt.$$

Then note

$$\tag 1 \frac{y}{(t-x)^2+y^2} = - \text {Im } \frac{1}{z-t}.$$

Thus, for fixed $t,$ $(1)$ is harmonic in $z=x+iy$ (no calculation necessary!). It follows that if $\Delta_z$ is the Laplacian in $z,$ then

$$\Delta_z u(z) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Delta_z \left [\frac{y}{(t-x)^2+y^2}\right]\,f(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}0\cdot\,f(t)\,dt =0.$$

This is all provided that differentiation across the integral sign is legit, which for your bounded function $f$ will be standard.

Comment: Ooh ... hmm...how did you remove the absolute value sign of the $y$ factor in the numerator @zhw.?  Thanks,

Comment: Oh, of course... $y>o$ on the UHP @zhw. :-) going to finish up this PBJ bagel and get back to work on this, thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @zhw., thanks for your answer.  I agree, and also it's clear from looking at the original integral expression that $u(x,y) = u(x,-y)$, and so this forces $u$ to be harmonic on the lower half plane as well.  For the last part of this question, how could I show that $\lim_{y\to 0}  u(x,y) = f(x)$?  I took the limit inside the integral, by the dominated convergence theorem, but that would just give me ... $0$.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: I think, $\dfrac y{(t-x)^2+y^2} = \dfrac y{(x-t)^2+y^2} =+Im\dfrac1{z-t}$

Comment: Thanks so much @YuriNegometyanov, yes, I played around with zhw.'s clever suggestion of taking the imaginary part of $\frac{1}{(z-t)} and am a bit more comfortable with it now.  :-)

Comment: Thanks again @zhw., I also found the limit, as $y\to 0$, which is immediate after a little bit of residue calculus, and being a bit careful with the finite summation $f(x)$, which wasn't too hard.  Thanks for sharing a very cool way of showing that $u$ is harmonic.  Now I know two ways to attack this problem :-)